# How to find point in Descartes Folium with slope of -1/3?

Tags: plane-curves, slope

I stumbled upon a problem in my calculus book that asked to find the point in $x^3 + y^3 = 3xy$ that had a slope perpendicualr to $y = 3x + 1$ and also was in the first quadrant.

I began by getting the derivative of the equation and got $\dfrac{x^2-y}{x-y^2}$.

Given that the slope is $-\frac13$, I wrote $\dfrac{x^2-y}{x-y^2}=-\frac13
$, which got me to $3x^2+x=y^2+3y$, and that is where I got stuck, because I cannot solve for $x$ or $y$, to substitute in the original equation.

I looked for similar examples on the internet, and only found some where the slope was $0$, which can be solved because $y = x^2$, which can be substituted back.

Hope this is redacted well enough, any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let's find a parametric equation of the curve defined by $x^3+y^3=3xy$.

Let $y=xt$, then

$$x^3(1+t^3)=3x^2t$$

Hence

$$x=\frac{3t}{1+t^3}$$
$$y=\frac{3t^2}{1+t^3}$$

Now, the tangent vector is given by

$$x'(t)=\frac{3(1+t^3)-3t(3t^2)}{(1+t^3)^2}=\frac{3-6t^3}{(1+t^3)^2}$$
$$y'(t)=\frac{6t(1+t^3)-3t^2(3t^2)}{(1+t^3)^2}=\frac{6t-3t^4}{(1+t^3)^2}$$

You want $t$ such that $y'(t)=-\frac13x'(t)$, that is

$$6t-3t^4=2t^3-1$$

You have thus a quartic equation to solve: $3t^4+2t^3-6t-1=0$. There does not seem to be a trivial solution, so you'll have to go through Descartes' or Ferrari's method to solve this, or a numerical method.

There are [two real roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots+of+3t%5E4%2B2t%5E3-6t-1) (hence two points), with numerically

$$t_1=-0.1678460300438111, x_1=-0.5059304363344097, y_1=0.0849184152170638$$
$$t_2=1.1301467382482941, x_2=1.3875575405757694, y_2=1.5681436286135308$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand what you mean "had a slope perpendicular to $y=3x+1$ ".

A slope is an number and $y=3x+1$ is the equation of a straight line. A number perpendicular to a line is non-sens.

I suppose that you mean "to find the point where the tangent to $x^3 + y^3 = 3xy$ is  perpendicular to $y = 3x + 1$ "

If so, the slope of the tangent must be $-\frac13$.

Differentiating $x^3 + y^3 = 3xy$ leads to :
$$3x^2dx+3y^2dy=3ydx+3xdy$$ 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-x^2}{y^2-x}$$
All the points $(x,y)$ where the slope of the tangent is $-\frac13$ are given by the system of equations :
$$\begin{cases}
x^3 + y^3 = 3xy \\
\frac{y-x^2}{y^2-x}=-\frac13
\end{cases}$$
Solve the system of equations for the points $(x,y)$ and select the point in the first quadrant. (Numerical solving).

In addition. The analytical solving leads to the exact formulas :

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 Interestingly, Descartes' method yields the very simple resolvent $z^3=4(p^3+1)$ when the slope is $p$. Hence $z=\frac{2}{3}\sqrt[3]{13}$ for $p=-1/3$, and those cube roots in the solution. It's not very difficult to find the coefficients of the quadric and to finish the resolution, but the formulas get quite long (though much shorter than the general case where the cubic is not so simple).

Comment: Slight simplification of notation: with $\zeta=\sqrt[3]{13},\eta=\sqrt[4]{9\zeta^2-26},\theta=\sqrt[4]{6\zeta+1}$,

$$x=\frac{\zeta}{26}\frac{\eta^3+\sqrt{650-\eta^6}}{\eta}$$
$$y=\frac{\zeta^2}{26}\frac{\theta^3+\sqrt{106-\theta^6}}{\theta}$$

Comment: @ Jean-Claude Arbaut : Exact and smart ! Why don't you edit it as an answer instead of a comment ?